# Problems downloading files via WeTransfer

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, downloads, browser

I have been using Ubuntu for a few months and everything works really fine. However, I do often get large files sent via the WeTransfer service. Unfortunately I am mostly not able to download them when using Ubuntu (first 14.10 now 15.04). I have tried different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, Epiphany) but most of the time when I access a page with a WeTransfer Link, the download will simply not start.

Comment: I don't have such issues...